# How to find an author that appears more than once in array of objects using higher order functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, functional-programming

How to find an author that that occurs more than once in this array using higher order functions? I'm pretty sure array.filter is the correct function, but I don't know which condition to set.

```
let knjige = {
lektira: [{
    naziv: "Zločin i kazna",
    autor: "Fjodor Mihajlovič Dostojevskog",
    br_str: 350,
    godina_izdavanja: 1866
}, {
    naziv: "Vlak u snijegu",
    autor: "Mato Lovrak",
    br_str: 150,
    godina_izdavanja: 1931
}, {
    naziv: "Mali princ",
    autor: " Antoine de Saint-Exupery",
    br_str: 120,
    godina_izdavanja: 1943
}, {
    naziv: "Rat i mir",
    autor: "Lav Nikolajevič Tolstoj",
    br_str: 300,
    godina_izdavanja: 1865
}, {
    naziv: "Ana Karenjina",
    autor: "Lav Nikolajevič Tolstoj",
    br_str: 800,
    godina_izdavanja: 1873
}]
```

};

```
let autorsWithMoreThanOneBook = knjige.lektira.filter(function(book){

  // TO DO filter authors with more than one book

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 knjige.lektira.filter(({author}, index) => knijge.lektira.findIndex(el => el.author === author) < index);
```

Just check if there is another book with the same author in the array. Now you can simply `map` those dupe author books to the authors. It might be more easy to set up a hashtable:

```
 const bookCount = {};
 for(const {author} of knijge.lektira)
   bookCount[author]++ || (bookCount[author] = 1);
```

Now you can go over every bookCount and only take the keys were the values are bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

You need more than `filter` in this case.  You could pluck each author from the array (`map`), produce an array of counts by author(`reduce`), then `filter` that array for `count > 1`, then finally `map` the `entry` back to just the author's name.  If modern JavaScript is available to you:

```
let autorsWithMoreThanOneBook = Object.entries(
    knjige.lektira
        .map(book => book.autor)
        .reduce((acc, autor) => {
          acc.hasOwnProperty(autor) ? acc[autor]++ : acc[autor] = 1
          return acc
        }, {})
)
   .filter(entry => entry[1] > 1)
   .map(entry => entry[0])

console.log(autorsWithMoreThanOneBook)
```

The features are available in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge these days, and NodeJS >= 7.

This is really just a big `reduce`: taking the original array and transforming it to an object with a different structure and number of elements.  But decomposing it into a pipeline, as I've done in my example, is often easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to go about this.  I personally suggest you use lodash groupBy, or you can roll your own reduce function.  A groupBy transformation is similar to a SQL group by... the object index is all the unique values for the group by field, and the values are all the items that have that value.

```
 {
  dostoyevsky: [... all the dostoyevsky books],
  king: [... all the king books],
  gogol: [...all the gogol books]
 }
```

i.e.

```
const groupedByAuthors = _.groupBy(knjige.lektira, 'autor')
//a list of autors that appear more than once
Object.keys(groupedByAuthors).filter(key => 
groupedByAuthors[key].length > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `map` with `sort` to get a sorted array of all the books, then `filter` it to get an array of duplicates like so:

```
knjige.lektira.map(elem => elem.autor).sort()
.filter( (elem, index, array) => elem === array[index+1]  
                              && elem !== array[index-1] )

// Outputs an array of authors with more than one book
```

Filtering in this way works because when the index is out of range `undefined` is returned from the callback and simply nothing is added to the filtered array.